# Fill SVG path does not work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to fill path color using the following code:

```
<path id="svg_23" d="m448,1395.555556c0,0 62.222222,1.777777 62.222222,1.777777c0,0 78.222222,-72.888889 78.222222,-72.888889c0,0 -3.555555,-92.444444 -3.555555,-92.444444c0,0 -135.111111,0 -135.111111,0" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>

d3.select("#svg_23").style("fill","red");
```

Comment: you can fill `polygons` not `path's`

Comment: The fill works perfectly well for me. If you create a [mcve] we might be able to look further into why it's not working for you.

Comment: @user1767754 that's not true, paths fill perfectly well in SVG.

Comment: Also unable to reproduce the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/uxt27vn8/1/

Comment: It turns out that the path has fill-opacity="0" property which make that code useless...thanks.

Comment: @Cassini  The code works with these errors, but without the wrong styles https://jsfiddle.net/4b9k2475/ The main reason for the invisibility of the svg figure, - an error in positioning,

Answer (score 0):

In svg were not specified `viewport`, `viewBox`

This is what your svg file looks like in the vector editor. It is evident that it falls outside the viewing area, so it was invisible.

[image]

To return a shape to the visibility zone, add `viewport`, `viewBox`

`width="200" heght="200" viewBox="350 1150 300 300"`

```html
<svg width="200" heght="200" viewBox="370 1170 300 300" style="border:1px solid red;">

<path id="svg_23" d="m448,1395.555556c0,0 62.222222,1.777777 62.222222,1.777777c0,0 78.222222,-72.888889 78.222222,-72.888889c0,0 -3.555555,-92.444444 -3.555555,-92.444444c0,0 -135.111111,0 -135.111111,0z" stroke-dasharray="0" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="red"/>

</svg>
```

The red frame shows the scope of SVG. It was needed for tuning, it can be removed now.

<strike>style="border:1px solid red;"</strike>

Comment: @ Robert Longson I have little experience in understanding the situation, am I doing something wrong? Why the minus?

Comment: Not sure why you're picking on me to write comments to (I don't get notified since I've not commented on your answer so you're lucky I saw this). If I was to guess I would say you're getting downvoted because this is not a correct answer. The OP stated in [comments their problem was fill-opacity="0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539887/fill-svg-path-does-not-work#comment82037779_47539887) which was rather hard to diagnose given that it's information that's not in the question. That comment was visible when you wrote your answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson  Thanks for the answer. I've wanted to tell you for a long time, but there was no opportunity. I've been reading your answers to questions on the stackoverflow website for several years. And I always admire the depth and breadth of your knowledge in the field of SVG.  Look please once again my answer, there yesterday I immediately removed all the errors in the styles in the author's question, including `fill-opacity =" 0 "`.

Comment: @RobertLongson The code works with these errors, but without the wrong styles https://jsfiddle.net/4b9k2475/  The main reason for the invisibility of the svg figure, - an error in positioning, I posted in my answer, for which I got downvoted